# Find two paths in a graph that are in distance of at least D(constant)

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, nodes, distance

**Instance of the problem:**
Undirected and unweighted graph G=(V,E).
two source nodes a and b, two destination nodes c and d and a constant D(complete positive number).(we can assume that lambda(c,d),lambda(a,b)>D, when lambda(x,y) is the shortest path between x and y in G).
we have two peoples standing on the nodes a and b.

**Definition**:scheduler set-
A scheduler set is a set of orders such that in each step only one of the peoples make a move from his node v to one of v neighbors, when the starting position of them is in the nodes a,b and the ending position is in the nodes c,d.A "scheduler set" is missing-disorders if in each step the distance between the two peoples is > D.

I need to find an algorithm that decides whether there is a "missing-disorders scheduler set" or not.

any suggestions?

Comment: This reminds me a bit of Dynamic Timewarping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution would be to first solve [all-pairs shortest paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) using n breadth-first searches from every node in O(n * (n + m)).

Then create the graph of valid node pairs (x,y) with lambda(x, y) > D, with edges indicating the possible moves. There is an edge {(v,w), (x,y)} if v = x and there is an edge {w, y} in the original graph or if w = y and there is an edge {v, x} in the original graph. This new graph has O(n^2) nodes and O(nm) edges.

Now you just need to check whether (c, d) is reachable from (a, b) in the new graph. This can be achieved using DFS or BFS.

The total runtime be O(n * (n + m)).

Comment: can you explain more about the first part of your answer?

Comment: @baza A node in the pair graph is a pair of nodes in the original graph that have a distance > D. I added a sentence on how to compute the shortest paths as well.

Comment: so every **node** in the pair graph is a pair pair of nodes in the original graph that have a distance > D? and what about the edges in the pair graph? what do they indicates?

Comment: @baza the pair represents the positions of the two people. An edge represents a move by one of them. I added a definition

Comment: sorry but i still don't completely understand the part of building the new graph. maybe an example will be great, if its not too hard..

Comment: @baza Maybe later, I got to go now. Just think about a node representing the positions of *both* people, not just one. Then you can ensure that your distance property holds at each step